# Should conciseness be a part of the "How do I ask a good question?" guide?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that questions that are as concise as possible without sacrificing clarity get more attention. More specifically, questions that avoid repeating information, avoid adding unnecessary context (e.g. the first paragraph in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52756/probability-of-overlap-between-independent-samples-of-different-sizes)), and ask a single question at a time. Should this be mentioned in the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) guide?

Comment: I would urge caution, because many questions don't contain enough information to be answerable.  We can foresee people objecting that this comes about because they were following instructions to be concise.  Thus, we need to make sure that concision is not confused with omitting useful information.  As far as "unnecessary context" goes -- you are politely referring to completely irrelevant passages -- everyone is encouraged to edit that out.  It's routine even to eliminate, without comment, the "please answer this question" or "thanks in advance" clauses that often appear.

Comment: @whuber, why don't you turn that into an official answer?